# Create file with date and information

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a file in a shell script. The file's name should be:

```
MyFile_datetoday.dat
```

Where `datetoday` is today's date in YYYYMMDD format. The contents of the file should be:

```
nameofmyfile;sysdate;numberofrecordosofanotherfile.dat
```

That is, one line with the name of the file, the system date and the number of records from another file.

anotherfile.dat:

```
105;One;fzstre;40502
108;One;jzsdre;6603
22;NoOne;kxstw;8892
```

So, the contents of the generated file would be:

```
MyFile_20160527.dat;2016/05/27 00:00;3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of the file you want to create. Should it actually contain the string `namefile;sysdate;numbers`? Or should those be specific numbers and a specific date and the file's actual name?

Comment: @terdon ok. Number of records of another file

Comment: As I said, please **[edit]** your question and add an *example*. What other file? What records? Do you mean the number of lines? How can we know what file?

Comment: Why are you counting 4 records in `anotherfile.dat`? What is a record? A line? A `;`-separated field? If you want to count fields, you need to explain how the fields are defined and what should happen if one of the lines has a different number of fields. If you want to count *lines* you should say so.

Comment: Sorry. I want to count records line

Comment: Please explain more clearly. What are records? How do you define a record?  What in the world is a "records line"? I see you edited to change the 3 to 4. Do you actually want to count the number fo lines in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
fname=MyFile_"$(date +%Y%d%M)".dat
echo "$fname;$(date +%D);$(wc -l < anotherfile.dat )" > "$fname"
```